# How to interpret variables as dictionary indices

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm attempting to map integers to indices of a string dictionary.
However, no substition occurs.
If I hard code ( `um[2]` for example), the substitution is correct.

What's a correct way of Getting It Done?

**DB Schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE users (id integer primary key autoincrement, user text not null, um tinyint not null);
```

**Generator:**

```
users = [dict(id=row[0], name=row[1], um=row[2]) for row in cur.fetchall()]
um = ["Limited", "Lessimited", "EvenLessLimited", "SuperUser"];
return render_template('show_users.html', users=users, um=um)
```

**Template:**

```
{% for user in users %}
 {% set m = user.um|int %}
 <tr><td class="id">{{ user.id }}</td><td> {{ um[m] }}</td></tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want `user["um"]`, not `user.um`.

Actually, you should want `user.um`, but for that you could use 'namedtuple`:

```
from collections import namedtuple
User = namedtuple('User', 'rowid name um')
users = [User(*row) for row incur.fetchall()]
um = ["Limited", "Lessimited", "EvenLessLimited", "SuperUser"];
return render_template('show_users.html', users=users, um=um)
```

**Template*:

```
{% for user in users %}
  <tr>
    <td class="id">
      {{ user.rowid }}</td><td> {{ um[user.um] }}
    </td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```